# Python decorator in a class: missing required positional arguments:

Tags: python, python-decorators, python-class, positional-argument

```
class Something:
    def __init__(self, ...):
       ...

    def update(self):
       ...

    def add_update(self, func):
      def fct(*args, **kwargs):
          self.update()
          func(*args, **kwargs)
      return fct 

    @add_update
    def method(self, some_parameter):
       ...
```

So basically I have this class, and I want to call the function "update()" automatically before I call a method from the class. But I get this error:

```
TypeError: add_update() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'
```

I don't really understand what's wrong here, also I saw some tutorials on the internet where they did something similar and it was working. Can someone explain me what's wrong here and how do I fix it?

Comment: You need to pass the argument func.

Comment: You're not using `add_update` as a method, you're using it as a decorator function, so it doesn't have a `self` argument. `self` will be the first argument to `fct`.

Answer (score 3):

What is a decorator? It's syntactic sugar for more verbose syntax.

```py
@decorator
def my_fun():
   ...
```

is the same as

```py
my_fun = decorator(my_fun)
```

So in your specific case

```py
method = add_update(method)
```

Do you see a problem? Add update expects two parameters (self, and func), but here it gets only one (and actually you pass **method** as **self**).

To solve this you need to create decorator outside the class that gets only function, and that functions first parameter will be self:

```py
def add_update(func):
     def wrapper(*args):
         self = args[0]
         ...
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use `@add_update`, It is equivalent to `add_update(method)`, At this time `add_update` is still a function.

You can make the following modifications to make it work

```
class Something:
    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def update(self):
        ...

    def add_update(f):
        def fct(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.update()
            return f(self, *args, **kwargs)

        return fct

    @add_update
    def method(self, some_parameter):
        ...
```

Comment: Now when I call the "method" method from the class. I get the following error:
method() missing 1 required positional argument: 'some_parameter'

Comment: `method` it is a method, it has parameters, you need to add parameters to it, such as
`Something().method(1)`

Comment: You may be using the above example instead of mine, where `Something.update()` is called instead of `args[0].update()`, so it will cause an error

Comment: I am using your example, and I did something like this:
test = Something(...)
test.method(some_parameter)
And I get this error: method() missing 1 required positional argument: 'some_parameter'

Comment: I run here and will not report an error, can you post a screenshot of your code

Comment: this is my code https://onlinegdb.com/Zj0MjcpZu

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the argument `func` and define the class inside the decorator function.

```
class Something:
    def __init__(self,..):
        ...
      

    def update(self):
       ...

    def add_update( func):
      def fct(*args, **kwargs):
          args[0].update() #or Something.update()
          func(*args, **kwargs)
      return fct 

    @add_update
    def method(self, some_parameter):
        ...
```

Comment: I get this error after modifying like this: update() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: You need to do it `Something.update()`, and I run it with no error.

Comment: You need to change `Something.update()` to `args[0].update()`, if your want, you can even change `Something.update()` to `Something.update(args[0])`, they are all the same

Comment: Both are  working.

Comment: `Something.update()` will have an error, because `Something.update` is a function instead of a method, and the self parameter is missing

Comment: I run the code https://onlinegdb.com/JF6W7FU8s

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/FgMzgbaWC

Comment: @ I_Al-thamary Thank you, I didn’t know until now that there is such a thing!!, which can make our communication more convenient.

Comment: or try this way without `self`:https://onlinegdb.com/7_L3LyD10

Comment: In this case, `update` will no longer support accessing self

Comment: yes, you are right.